# How to align li side by side with boostrap 3

Tags: html, css

I would like to have my icon `<i>` and my text `<h3><p>` side by side, and not one on top of the other. I have been trying `float:left;` and `display:inline-block;` but nothing works...

Help anyone?
Thanks a lot.

My HTML

```
<div class="steps">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="row">
   <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-4">
    <ul class="step">
     <li><i class="fa fa-question fa-4x"></i></li>
     <li><h3>Ask</h3><p>Talk 1-on-1 with caring professionals who are online and ready to help you now.</p></li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

My CSS

```
.steps ul li {
display:inline-block;
float:left;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
.step li {
  display: table; 
}

.step li:first-child {
  float: left;    
}
```

[Demo link](http://www.bootply.com/120735)

Comment: Thanks mutil! That worked, except that now they are all 3 inline.
And I want to have the h3 and the p on top of each other. Only the icon and the text block should be side by side.

Comment: That works pefectly! Thanks mutil!
It works even without display:table. (What is the purpose of this display btw?)

Thanks again!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. For more details about the display property, have a look [here](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/d/display/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to put the class selector next to the ul.

```
ul.steps li {
    display: inline-block;
    float: left;
}
```

View in a browser's style sheet viewer (F12 on most modern browsers) and make sure these styles aren't being out trumped by a bootstrap style. If it is you will have to make this more specific, for example add a class to li and then add that to your css selector.

Comment: Thanks for adding more lines, the original selectors you had are right. What is actually probably happening is inline-block is putting them on separate rows. Try removing that line or changing to display: inline.